# Why generic type of given function cannot be inferred in typescript?

Tags: typescript

Why generic type `Item` in `flatAndMerge` cannot be inferred? It's unknown.

```
type ItemRecord<Item> = Record<string, Item>

export const objectToFlatList = <Item>(data: ItemRecord<Item>) =>
  Object.keys(data).map((key) => ({ key, ...data[key] }));

export const flatAndMerge = <
  Item,
  T extends Record<string, ItemRecord<Item>>,
>(
  data: T,
  fields: (keyof T)[],
) => fields.flatMap((field) => objectToFlatList(data[field]));

const a = flatAndMerge(
  {
    a: {
      aa: { foo: 'foo' } ,
      ab: { foo: 'foo' },
    },
    b: {
      ba: { foo: 'foo' },
      bb: { foo: 'foo' },
    },
    c: {
      ca: { foo: 'foo' },
      cb: { foo: 'foo' },
    },
  } as Record<string, ItemRecord<{ foo: string }>>, //
  ['a', 'c'],
);
```

[image: Inferred generic types for a flatAndMerge call]

[image: Types for results]

As a remark: `objectToFlatList` inferring type correctly.

Comment: [Please replace images of code/logs/errors with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218)

Comment: Constraints are not used as inference sites, as mentioned in [ms/TS#7234](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7234), so there's nowhere from which TS can infer `Item` (no parameter of type `Item` exists in that function).  Does that fully address your question?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, I think so and it sounds logical. Of course this is not question to you, but I still need to figure out how to do it - I mean how to keep type of 'fields' (keys only) and to keep type of nested object (Item).

Comment: Maybe something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Nnl9BW) but as you say that's out of scope for this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type argument for the type parameter `Item` cannot be inferred because the only reference to `Item` in the call signature is as a [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) on the `T` type parameter, and constraints are not used as inference sites in TypeScript.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#7234](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7234) for an ultimately declined request to infer type arguments from constraints.

That means when you call `flatAndMerge()`, the type argument for `T` can easily be inferred from the argument passed as `data`, but there is no place from which `Item` can be inferred.  So it falls back to its constraint, which is implicitly [the `unknown` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#unknown).